# Why is my code only printing my method and not continuing with the rest?

Tags: arrays, string, output

I'm supposed to ask the user to enter a bagel code, ask if they want more, and an output file should be made, but none of this happens, the only thing that happens is the printMenu method.

**This is my code:**

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class Lab5
  {//start of class
  public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {//start of main
  Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
  // assigns "keyIn" to keyboardScanner 

  Scanner bagelFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Lab5Input.txt"));
  //open the input file 


  //Data Dictionary - declare variables

  int sub; 
  int bagelCode;
  int bagelQuantity;  
  int moreBagels=1;
  double totalCost; //75 cents per bagel
  int totalQuantity=0;
  boolean inputBad = true;  

  //create arrays for description, inventory

  String [ ] descArray = new String [13]; 
  int [ ] invArray = new int [13];

//Load Bagel arrays from input file  - use a while loop

  sub = 0; 
  while(bagelFile.hasNext())
  {
  descArray[sub] = bagelFile.next();
  invArray[sub] = bagelFile.nextInt(); 
  sub ++; 
  }

  // start a customer

  System.out.println("Welcome to Dan's Bagel House, here's our menu: "); 
  System.out.println(""); 
  System.out.println(""); 

  // print menu

  printMenu (descArray, invArray, 13);
  while (moreBagels==1);  // moreBagels = 1

  {//begin while loop for one customer

  totalCost = 0;

  //verify bagel code 

  do
  {
  System.out.print ("\nEnter bagel # ");
  bagelCode = keyIn.nextInt();
  if (bagelCode >=1 && bagelCode<= 13)
  inputBad= false; 

  }//end of loop
  while (inputBad);

  sub = bagelCode - 1;    

  // verify quantity
  inputBad = true; 

  do
  {
  System.out.print("Please enter quantity of bagels");
  bagelQuantity = keyIn.nextInt ( ); 

  if (bagelQuantity >= 0 && bagelQuantity <= invArray[sub])
  inputBad = false; 
  }
  while (inputBad);

  totalQuantity = totalQuantity + bagelQuantity;
  invArray[sub] = invArray[sub] - bagelQuantity;  

  //one bagel purchase complete

  //do you want more bagels 1 or 0

  inputBad = true;
  do
  {
  System.out.print ("Do you want additional bagels? Enter 1 for Yes or 0 for No");
  moreBagels = keyIn.nextInt( ); 
  if (moreBagels == 1 || moreBagels ==2)
  inputBad = false; 
  }
  while (inputBad); 

  }//end while loop for one customer    

  totalCost = totalQuantity * .75; 

  //end of a customer

  System.out.print("Thank you for your purchase"); 
  printReport (descArray, invArray, 13);

  }//end of main

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////printMenu Method///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  public static void printMenu (String [ ] mDescArray, int [ ] mInvArray, int maxIndex)
  {

  System.out.println("Bagel Code      Description      Current Inventory ");
  int mSub;

  for (mSub = 0; mSub<13; mSub++)
  {   

  int m = mSub+1;

  System.out.printf("%6d",m);
  System.out.printf(" %20s",mDescArray[mSub]);
  System.out.printf("%15d%n",mInvArray[mSub]); 
  }

  }//end of main

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////printReport Method///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  public static void printReport (String [ ] mDescArray, int [ ] mInvArray, int maxIndex) throws FileNotFoundException
  {//declare output file here

  PrintWriter outBagelFile = new PrintWriter("Lab5Output.txt");
  outBagelFile.println ("Bagel Code      Description      Current Inventory ");

  int mSub;

  for (mSub = 0; mSub<13; mSub++);
  {
  int m = mSub+1;    
  outBagelFile.printf("%4d",m);
  outBagelFile.printf(" %-15s",mDescArray[mSub]);
  outBagelFile.printf("%4d%n",mInvArray[mSub]);
  }
  outBagelFile.close( );

  }//end of main

  }//end of class
```

**This is the output:**

```
  Welcome to Dan's Bagel House, here's our menu: 


  Bagel Code      Description      Current Inventory 
       1         asiagocheese             12
       2            blueberry             12
       3        cheddarcheese              6
       4           everything             12
       5               garlic             12
       6                honey              4
       7             jalepeno              3
       8           multigrain             12
       9                onion             12
      10            poppyseed             12
      11               raisin              6
      12               sesame             12
      13           wholewheat             12
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to print a message if there is not enough quantity:

```
if (bagelQuantity >= 0 && bagelQuantity <= invArray[sub])
    inputBad = false; 
else
    System.out.print("Not enough quantity");
```

Also, use either array length or maxIndex in printMenu and printReport, instead of hard coded number 13, and remove the semi-colon after the for (";") in printReport:

```
for (mSub = 0; mSub < maxIndex; mSub++)
```

The error is obviously in the first while, there is ";" at the end of it, remove it:

```
while (moreBagels == 1)  // moreBagels = 1
```

Also, when asking for more bagels check for 0, not for 2:

```
if (moreBagels == 1 || moreBagels == 0)
    inputBad = false;
```

And finally take it easy !